# Median marker style in BoxWhiskerChart

Tags: graphics, plotting

I was trying to adapt the `BoxWhiskerChart` to obtain a minimalistic quartile plot, like this:

[image: Quartile plot]

What I obtained is the plot below that is, however, unsatisfying; the median markers should be circles, but they are instead slightly squared.

[image: Quartile plot with wrong median markers]

The code:

```
data = Table[
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[μ, 1], 100], {μ, 
    RandomInteger[{-2, 2}, 10]}];
filledCircle[size_] := Graphics[{Black, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> size];
BoxWhiskerChart[data,
  {{"Whiskers", Black},
   {"MedianMarker", filledCircle[10], Black},
   {"Fences", None}},
  ChartBaseStyle -> White,
  Frame -> False,
  Method -> {"BoxRange" -> (Quantile[#, 
        Range[0, 1, 1/4], {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}] &)}
  ]
```

As an alternative, I've tried to rasterize the circles; the shape is now correct, but we get a lateral shift of the median marker.

```
filledCircle[size_] := Rasterize[Graphics[{Black, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> size]];
```

[image: Quartile plot with shift]

Does anyone have a better approach or solution? Or should I just build my own function?

Comment: Not sure how this helps,  when I run your code the circles are definitely more circular than the ones shown in your first example, when zoomed to 300%, the left rightish quadrant has slightly octagonal edges, but the rest is circular. I'm on 8.0.4 on Linux.

Comment: @image_doctor If I set `filledCircle[50]` then they look more circular, but I'm looking for a solution with smaller circles.

Comment: Does `filledCircle[size_] :=Style[Graphics[{Black, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> size], Antialiasing -> True]` give something close to what you need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The disks aren't getting antialiased.  (This is probably leaking from turning off antialiasing for the lines and rectangles.)

If you turn antialiasing back on:

```
filledCircle[size_] := 
    Graphics[{Black, Style[Disk[], Antialiasing -> True]}, 
        ImageSize -> size]
```

it should look better:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It looks like that the problem is solved. I like your solution better, because it gives more freedom in defining the shape of the marker than using symbols like `\[FilledCircle]` and the like.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a FilledCircle rather than creating the Disk:

```
data = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[μ, 1], 100], {μ, 
RandomInteger[{-2, 2}, 10]}];


BoxWhiskerChart[data,
                {{"Whiskers", Black},
                {"MedianMarker", Style[\[FilledCircle], 45], Black},
                {"Fences", None}},
                ChartBaseStyle -> White,  Frame -> False,  
                Method -> {"BoxRange" -> 
                (Quantile[#,Range[0, 1, 1/4], {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}] &)}
                ]
```

Here is an example with the typical format overlaid:

```
Show[
      BoxWhiskerChart[data,
                     {{"Whiskers", Black},
                     {"MedianMarker",Style[\[FilledCircle], 30], Black},       
                     {"Fences", None}},
                     ChartBaseStyle -> White, Frame -> False, 
                     Method -> {"BoxRange" ->
                    (Quantile[#,Range[0, 1, 1/4], {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}] &)}],
      BoxWhiskerChart[data, {{"Fences", None}},ChartBaseStyle ->Opacity[.75]]
   ]
```

[image]

Comment: But those are also shifted.

Comment: what operating system are you using VLC?

Comment: @chuy Os X 10.6.8

Comment: Changed to a filled circle.  Looks better now I think.